# a lot of decimal value storage in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wanted to write a program that returns how many months we could survive when we're given 
our monthly expenditure, amount of disposable income, and interest rate (all in integers). 
For instance, if we start with disposable income = 1000, interest rate = 5%, monthly expenditure = 100, then

```
after first month: 1000*1.05 - 100 = 950, we have 950 dollars left
after second month: = 950*1.05 - 100 = 897.5
```

and so on, and in the end, we can survive 14 months.

I wrote the following code in C++:

```
int main(){

int i=0;
int initialValue;
int interest;
int monthly; 
double value=1.0*initialValue;
double r=1+1.0*interest/100;
while(value > 0){
    if(value < monthly){
        break;
    }
    else
    {
    value=value*r-monthly;  
    i++;
    }
};
cout<<i;
return 0;
}
```

but for sufficiently large values of initialValue and small values of monthly, the program I wrote runs very slowly to the degree that it's unusable. Is there a problem with the code that makes it run not well (or very slow)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Think about what happens if you make more in interest than your expenses each month....

Comment: For "sufficiently large values of initialValue and small values of monthly", wouldn't you expect i to be very large, and thus take a long time to count that high?

Comment: @uesp  for test cases, I removed such cases, so that wasn't the problem, causing i to go infinity

Answer (score 1):

`double` cannot store numbers precisely. One consequence of this is when you subtract a very small number from a very large number, the result is not changed from the original large value.

One solution to this problem is to use an `int` to do your calculations. Think of the values as the number of pennies, rather than the number of dollars.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- The `*1.0`'s are pointless. Instead, take advantage of implicit and explicit casts:

  double value=initialValue;
  double r=1+(double)interest/100;
- `++i` is faster than `i++`.
- `value=value*` can be rewritten as `value*=`.
- You can mix the first two conditionals. Remove the `if...break` and change the while loop to `while (value > 0 && value < monthly)`.

Comment: any sane compiler will have no performance difference for `i++;` and `++i;` as single statements.

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it, the reason this runs slowly is the large number of iterations. However, you didn't specify any specific numbers and I would expect this code to be able to execute at least a million iterations per second on any reasonably fast processor. Did you really expect to need to calculate more than 1 million months?

Apart from the novice style of the code, the underlying problem is the algorithm. There are very simple formulae for making these calculations, which you can find here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest. Your situation is akin to paying off a loan, where running out of money equals loan paid off.